# Short form of map for other class methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda

Some time ago, I read a blog article, in which i definitely saw the lambda form like:

```
arr.map(OtherClass.method *arr_element*)
```

Where *arr_element* - unknown part.
it's like

```
arr.map(&:to_i)
```

but not for iterated class methods.

For example, i need to check array for Prime number:

```
require 'prime'

p [1, 11, 13, 18].all? { |y| Prime.prime? y }
```

I need more short form of this expression.

Comment: What’s the question? Your first example isn’t valid, and it seems like your second isn’t what you’re trying to emulate, so what is the valid statement you’re (maybe) looking for the equivalent of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-method) on an object to get a [Method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html) instance, then use `&` to convert it to a block (since Method responds to [`to_proc`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-to_proc):

```
[1, 11, 13, 18].all?(&Prime.method(:prime?))
```

Of course, in many cases this might not be fewer characters, but if you use this many times you can store it in a variable:

```
is_prime = Prime.method(:prime?)

[1, 11, 13, 18].all?(&is_prime)
[1, 17, 7, 321].all?(&is_prime)
```

Comment: Ruby is already dangerously easy to obfuscate. IMO your first example goes beyond decency.

Comment: @Borodin Yea I’ve only really used this for something like the second one. The first one usually doesn’t save you any characters and is less clear (common).

Comment: `require 'prime'`defines a `prime?` method on Integer, so:
p [1, 11, 13, 18].all?(&:prime?)`

Answer (score 6):

> As you said arr.map(OtherClass.method *arr_element*)

Here is one example to meet the above:

```
a = %w(foo.rb bar.xml)
a.map(&File.method(:extname)) # equivalent to a.map{|e| File.extname(e) }
# => [".rb", ".xml"]
```

Use `a.map{|e| File.extname(e) }` form,as it is always faster!

**Becnhmark**

```
require 'benchmark'

a = %w(foo.rb bar.xml foo.c baz.dll) * 100000

Benchmark.bm(10) do |b|
  b.report("short form")    { a.map(&File.method(:extname)) }
  b.report("usual one") { a.map{|e| File.extname(e) } }
end
```

**output**

```
                 user     system      total        real
short form   0.600000   0.020000   0.620000 (  0.618438)
usual one    0.340000   0.000000   0.340000 (  0.344993)
```